# Can only select the entire vehicle model when in object mode

Tags: object-mode

I am fairly new to blender.  For some reason while in object mode I can not select individual pieces (bumper, hood, ect) of the vehicle model.  It will only let me select the entire model or the wheel.  I thought it may have been a vehicle file issue but it has done the same thing with every single vehicle model I have imported into blender.  I am using Sollumz and exporting from codewalker as XML file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The picture below is what I mean when I say it will only let me select the entire vehicle.

[image]

Comment: Sollumz is not a part of Blender so I have no idea what it does, but the answer to why you can only select everything in _Object Mode_ is simple: all parts are joined in a single object. Does the original model consist of one object? I don't know without knowing the original file. If you want to have separate parts, go into _Edit Mode_, hover your mouse over one part and press `L`, this select only parts of the mesh that are connected to the one you had your cursor on. Then press `P` > _Separate_ > _Selection_. You can also choose _By Loose Parts_ but maybe that are too many...